# Why are the subsection headings centered beginning at subsection 10 in r markdown file (.Rmd)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am using RStudio to issue homework-each question as a subsection with total of 11 questions. But beginning at subsection 10, the subsection heading is centered instead of left aligned in pdf, while all subsections are left aligned in word and html files. I wonder if anybody could help me with that?

```
---
title: 'Math 710: HW#1'
author: "John Smith"
date: 'Due: by 12a.m. 9/9/2022'
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---

## 1. (4 points) 

## 2. (4 points) 

## 3. (4 points) 

## 4. (4 points) 

## 5. (4 points) 

## 6. (4 points) 

## 7. (4 points) 

## 8. (4 points) 

## 9. (4 points) 

## 10. (4 points) 

## 11. (4 points)
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your output? I do get all subsections left aligned https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfdqy.png

Comment: You're right! In order to make the table centered, I add

Comment: You're right. In order to make table centered, I add ` <!-- \centering -->
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Sample Number & Sample, S & P(S) & sample observations & sample mean $\bar{y}$ \\ \hline
1             & 1,2,4     & 1/4  &                     &             \\ \hline
2             & 2,3,6     & 1/2  &                     &             \\ \hline
3             & 1,3,5     & 1/4  &                     &             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}     `     The `\centering` does not make the table centered, but makes the subsection title centered. Thanks